# what is the Linux equivalent of ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am using ubuntu 20.0.4.

I am brand new to programming on linux. need help with finding out whats the linux equivalent of `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xterm control sequence

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(b'\33]0;title you want\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

will do the job but you can get fancier

in python 3.x

```
print('\33]0;title you want\a', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or in python 3.3 or better

```
print('\33]0;title you want\a', end='', flush=True)
```

or

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\33]0;title you want\a')
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```